# Añadir icono con pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Según he estado leyendo, a ver si alguien me puede aclara mi duda...
Es cierto que solo puedo hacer que mi aplicación tenga el icono deseado si la hago con --onefile?? no puedo hacerlo sin --onefile??

```
pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole --icon=miicono.ico myfile.py
```

gracias de antemano

Comment: si sabés usar algún editor de recursos como Resource Hacker ,creas el exe como quieras y después le cambias el recurso.

Answer (score 2):

La aplicación tendrá tu icono en modo archivo único y en modo de carpeta de distribución, ya que el icono es almacenado directamente en el exe, para archivo único, y enlazado para carpeta de distribución

intenta modificar el archivo spect, para que apunte al archivo de icono, ya que a veces, no se genera correctamente, esta dirección debe ser un string y la ruta completa de donde se encuentre, así también verifica que el archivo icono tenga sus diferentes tamaños, para evitar problemas al mostrarse

> **Nota**
>
> Si usas windows, es probable que la aplicación ya tenga el icono, pero
> debido al caché almacenado de los iconos mostrados con anterioridad,
> impida que veas tu icono del archivo EXE correctamente